# how do i read textbox per line, open chrome with chrome driver then close and try the next line?

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

```
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("xxxxxx");
        {

            driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("god");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("admin");


        }


    }
}
```

}

How can i read a textbox1.text in the form and change the "username" every time?

example:
textbox1.text contains:
gold
silver
bronze

open url
username: gold password: admin login close chrome driver
open url
username: silver password: admin login close chrome driver
open url
username: bronze password: admin login close chrome driver

Sorry if this sounds really newbie and stupid i am new to c#

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: or even just have a combolist in textbox1.text and change ("god"); & ("admin"); to the user:pass in the textbox1.text but how can i do this line by line?  gold:admin silver:admin bronze:admin

Comment: can you share url here or web elements so that we can get clear idea